# Nesting two divs next to each other - WordPress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm creating a WordPress theme and can't get two posts to nest next to each other correctly, the guys on the WP forums haven't been any help (one response). Without any of the WP hookups (the PHP stuff) the divs nest correctly, I styled and structured them like this:

CSS:

```
.singlecolumnpost .post {
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

.twocolumnpost .post {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
}

.singlecolumnpost img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 940px;
    max-height: 529px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0;
}

.twocolumnpost img {
    max-width: 460px;
    max-height: 259px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    z-index: 4;
}

.post-thumb {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id = "main">
    <div class = "singlecolumnpost">
        <div class = "post">
            <div class = "post-thumb">
                <a href = "#"><img src = "img/db.jpeg"</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "twocolumnpost">
        <div class = "post">
            <div class = "post-thumb">
                <a href = "#"><img src = "img/db.jpeg"</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "post 2">
            <div class = "post-thumb 2">
                <a href = "#"><img src = "img/db.jpeg"</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "singlecolumnpost">
        <div class = "post">
            <div class = "post-thumb">
                <a href = "#"><img src = "img/db.jpeg"</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works because I declared a post class twice inside the twocolumnpost. Now for the wordpress structure (same styling):

```
<div class = "twocolumnpost">
    <div <?php post_class() ?>>
        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>                            
            <div class = "post-thumb">
                <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                <div class = "caption">
                    <p class = "caption-text">Caption</p>    
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

This makes them nest weirdly as you can see here: http://suburbia.comoj.com/wordpress/

I'm struggling to get them to play ball and just sit next to each other with the correct padding and I'm not sure if this is because I've only declared one post in the twocolumnpost. If I do declare two posts, it doubles the image which isn't right.

So what I'm asking, is either to have the posts aligning nicely with current structure, or a method of checking the previous post for the first post id, and displaying the next one on the second post.

Comment: Are you able to tell me where your div class `pagination` is coming from? It looks like that's what's messing you up (at least at first glance).  It seems this `pagination` div is creating itself every time there's a post.  It has a minimum height, and is pushing every post down, including your second two-column post.  I just deleted the pagination between the two and it lined up, not perfectly, but better.

Comment: as a side note - Pagination is a term used for the numbering of pages to load the next set of posts.  If it's loading after every post, you're going to have a problem with numbers being under every post once you get past the pagination threshold

Comment: Cheers, as sad in below comment, did not realise I'd moved pagination inside the while, cheers for your help, if you had an answer it would have been the accepted one too!

Comment: No problem!  points are secondary here to me.  I'm just glad I could help.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get rid of the empty pagination `div` ntgCleaner is right that is messing it up.

The other thing is that your CSS applies a 5px padding to `.twocolumnpost img` but the post on the left isn't an image, it's a video in an `iframe` tag so that isn't being applied. Either change the CSS selector to be `.twocolumnpost img, .twocolumnpost iframe` or remove the padding.

This is what it looked like when I did that:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't have the pagination inside the while loop before, I can't really remember moving it there but thanks so much, completely forget the video was an iframe too because it's set as a featured image so I had it in my head "image".